# No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484 available for offline mode

Tags: gradle, android-studio-2.0

Is there any offline option present in gradle setting of the latest version of android studio ?

Comment: Consider editing your post to add more details on your issue: the context, what you have already tried to solve your issue... Pay attention to the wording of your sentences, and its punctuation. As such, I am affraid it won't get much attention.

Comment: I was also facing such error from tomorrow after updating. now i've solved my error, how i do it, i have recorded a video specially for you.  
I hope after watching this video, your problem will be solved.
https://youtu.be/sVBi6J9ygNE

Answer (score 8):

Just disable gradle offline mode and try, will work fine.

To disable offline mode in Android Studio 3.6.1

1. Click on gradle window (on right side of studio)
2. Select the project
3. Click [Toggle Offline Mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#3.6-gradle-offline-ui) button (disable here)

Answer (score 1):

I tried toggling offline mode (by clicking on it). It doesn't do anything.

***Edit:*** Finally got it working, and this is I did:

Open the *build.gradle* file from your app folder, it should look similar to this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

add *google()* to *repositories* in -**buildscript and allprojects** just like this :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()       // here
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()      //and here
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In Android Studio, go to **File** -> **Project Structure..**   *[ shortcut : **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S** ]*

In the ***Project*** tab : Android Gradle Plugin Version -> 3.6.1 **and** Gradle Version -> 5.6.4 |||

Last, under the ***Module*** tab, make sure the compile sdk version is > 14 (ie: 25, 28 or 29..)

Answer (score 0):

Check the SDK version installed in android studio in starting configure SDK manager and check that what version of android is installed.Install other version of android according to requirement also in project structure check the module, set it to android lolipop or lower version. Then toggle offline mode in gradle settings. Sync your project with gradle file,then try running it.