# Android Studio build gradle failded

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build

I have recently downloaded Android studio version 3.6.3 . When I create a new project I get these errors:

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'classpath'    
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6.4.
No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6.4. available for offline mode.
```

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6.4'
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How should I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484 available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467308/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-6-1-6040484-available-for-o)

Comment: @Tom No, it was not the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the gradle version and the gradle plugin version:

The **gradle plugin** `5.6.4` doesn't exist.
Use:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

The version of **gradle** is defined in the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Comment: I changed that to gradle:3.6.3 but I still get those errors (Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3.)

Comment: Check if you enabled the "Offline work" .
Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle.

Comment: I did that, but unfortunately that doesn't work either